# replace text in a div by pressing a button

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following project: http://jsfiddle.net/TXQ9U/40/

What i would to accomplish is that when I (".button2") my   is replaced by other content (containing question 2). I familiar with .html function so I can replace the content by of  by this:

```
 $(".button2").on("click",function(){
 $("#inner").html('Dit is pagina 2');

 });
```

But I do not only want to insert text, I also want this (see below) to be copied, but then with new values:

```
 <p> Question 1: what sport does Roger Federed play? </p>
<table width = "200">

    <tr>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" class="a1" value="a1" /> Cricket </td>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" class="a2" value="a1" /> Tennis </td>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" class="a3" value="a1" /> Tennis </td>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" class="a4" value="a1" /> Tennis </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would recommend researching JQuery template engines, like [this one for example](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)

Comment: use `$("#inner").append('Dit is pagina 2')`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
$(".button2").on("click",function(){
    strText = $("#inner").clone(); // clone data
    $('p',strText).html(' Question 2: what sport does Roger Federed play2?');
    $('.a1',strText).text('new value1');//modify cloned data
    $('.a2',strText).text('new value2');
    $('.a3',strText).text('new value3');
    $('.a4',strText).text('new value4');
    $("#inner").html(strText); //set it to show

});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TXQ9U/50/)

Comment: @user181796: did you test it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
<table width = "200" id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" class="a1" value="a1" /> Cricket </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" class="a2" value="a1" /> Tennis </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" class="a3" value="a1" /> Tennis </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" class="a4" value="a1" /> Tennis </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and your js:

```
$(".button2").on("click",function(){
    var clone = $('#myTable').clone();
    $("#inner div").empty().append(clone);
});
```

Beware: you must edit your html like this:

```
<div id="inner">
<div>
<p> Question 1: what sport does Roger Federed play? </p>
<table width = "200" id="myTable">

    <tr>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" class="a1" value="a1" /> Cricket </td>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" class="a2" value="a1" /> Tennis </td>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" class="a3" value="a1" /> Tennis </td>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" class="a4" value="a1" /> Tennis </td>
    </tr>

</table>
    </div>
```